# Como inserir resultado de consulta no mysql com python

Tags: mysql, python, raspberry-pi

Preciso inserir no banco de dados o resultado desta consulta através do médulo de temperatura.

O código é este.

A temperatura e umidade já estão retornando, porém não salva no banco de dados os valores.

```
# Carrega as bibliotecas
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import MySQLdb
import Adafruit_DHT
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="sensores")
cursor = db.cursor()

# Define o tipo de sensor
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11
#sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Define a GPIO conectada ao pino de dados do sensor
pino_sensor = 4

# Informacoes iniciais
print ("*** Lendo os valores de temperatura e umidade");

while(1):
   # Efetua a leitura do sensor
   umid, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pino_sensor);
   # Caso leitura esteja ok, mostra os valores na tela
   if umid is not None and temp is not None:
     print ("Temperatura = {0:0.1f}  Umidade = {1:0.1f}\n").format(temp, umid);
     cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO temperatura (temp, umidade) VALUES ('temp', 'umid')""")
     db.commit()
     print ("Aguarda 5 segundos para efetuar nova leitura...\n");
     time.sleep(5)
   else:
     # Mensagem de erro de comunicacao com o sensor
     print("Falha ao ler dados do DHT11 !!!")
```

Comment: Renomeie o título da sua pergunta para que o nome da mesma especifique o conteúdo. Sugestão: "Como inserir no banco de dados o resultado de uma consulta". É só uma sugestão :)

Comment: Qual o erro Vinicius ?

Comment: não grava o resultado no banco.

Comment: Você está passando as strings ` 'temp', 'umid' ` nos `VALUES` do `INSERT` não deveriam ser as variaveis `temp` e `umid`

Answer (score 1):

Altere sua linha:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO temperatura (temp, umidade) VALUES ('temp', 'umid')""")
```

Para essa aqui:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO temperatura (temp, umidade) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (temp, umid)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Viniciius,

quando você utiliza três aspas duplas seguidas em python, você está fazendo uma string de documentação, ou [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Então todo o código que está dentro das 3 aspas duplas é ignorado.

Tente trocar o seu:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO temperatura (temp, umidade) VALUES ('temp', 'umid')""")
```

para:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO temperatura (temp, umidade) VALUES ('temp', 'umid')")
```

Comment: Rubico, isso vai inserir as *strings* `'temp'` e `'umid'` no banco. Eu desconfio que o OP queira mesmo é inserir o valores das variáveis `temp` e `umid`.